# How do I free a form that's owned by something else?

Tags: delphi

I have a form dynamically created that needs to be destroyed:

- later (at application shutdown) IF `AssignData` succeeds, or
- immediately in case `AssignData` crashes.

Since the form is owned by the application, it is not safe to just call `FreeAndNil` on it. But `Close` also won't work; it won't close the window.

```
FrmLoader:= TFrmLoader.Create(Application);  <----- Application is the Owner                            
TRY
  FrmLoader.AssignData(FileData);                                      
EXCEPT                                                              
  FreeAndNil(FrmLoader);  // <------ unsafe                                            
  FrmLoader.Close;        // <------ this is the safe method to close it but won't work
  RAISE;       
END;
FrmLoader.DoStuff;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to call `Free` on a form that is owned. Or pass the form to `FreeAndNil`. And that is the right way to dispose of your form.

So, this code does what you need.

```
FrmLoader:= TFrmLoader.Create(Application);
TRY
  FrmLoader.AssignData(FileData);                                      
EXCEPT                                                              
  FreeAndNil(FrmLoader);
  RAISE;       
END;
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. (I have to wait 9 minutes before I can accept your answer.)